# Linux File Locking in Java

Tags: java, linux, file, locking

I know we can lock a file in linux using flock(). However, NFS drive might not support file lock.

I am thinking to implement some custom file lock logic in my java code, to support file lock on any drive. Can anyone suggest a good practice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

File locking must be done by the operating system kernel / file system drivers, unless you're thinking of a narrower scope like just locking between the threads of a single process. There's no way all the other processes on the system will know to talk to your application to lock/unlock without them being rewritten to do so. This is even more significant when thinking about distributed locking like what NFS does (although as you note, there are many broken NFS implementations that don't do it well).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new file yourself which you use as a lockfile (the following is an example in Java since you stated that you wanted to implement some custom file lock logic in Java):

```
File lockFile = new File(".filelock");
if(!lockFile.exists()){
   //create lock file
   boolean success = lockFile.createNewFile();       

   //execute some logic...

   //delete lock file
   lockFile.delete();                                
}else{
   //lock file exists, cannot execute the logic that we wanted
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it, but if my process exits in the middle without deleting the file. The file will be locked forever..

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29

Comment: ... and if the above fails, you could check for a living process after finding a lockfile (put the pid in the file), and prompt to delete the lockfile if finding none. Like what vim and emacs do with swap/backup files.

Comment: This example won't work in a multi-threaded environment (which is exactly when you want locking).

Imagine processes A and B both running this code at once. A tests to see if the lock file exists; it doesn't, so A enters the top branch. Then B runs the same line. The file doesn't exist yet, so B also enters the top branch. A then creates the file; next B runs and tries to create the file (though by now it already exists). But by this stage it's too late - both processes are already running your supposedly-locked code.

You need the "create file if it doesn't exist" to be an atomic operation.

Comment: @sam true, or you could declare the method as synchronized.

Comment: @p_strand, Is it even posible to Java `synchronized` across processes?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Standard Library does not expose `flock()` or `fnctl()` directly. It seems to use `lockf()` in [FileChannel/FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock(long,%20long,%20boolean)) - but I wouldn't count on it using `lockf()` if you need to be sure. From the libraries point of view, this is an implementation details that can change.

If you actually want to use the specific posix function, take a look at [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix) and related projects. Here's an example how you could use it. Beware, this is basically writing low-level C in Java, but that's the goal after all, right? :)

```
// couldn't find these in jnr-posix...
// from http://linux.die.net/include/sys/file.h
/* Operations for the `flock' call.  */
public static final int LOCK_EX = 2;    /* Exclusive lock.  */
public static final int LOCK_UN = 8;    /* Unlock.  */
/* Can be OR'd in to one of the above.  */
public static final int LOCK_NB = 4;    /* Don't block when locking.  */

private static void throwErrno(String fn, Path path) throws IOException {
    int err = posix.errno();
    throw new IOException(fn + "() returned errno " + err + " '" + Errno.valueOf(err) + "' for " + path );
}

public int flock(Path path, int mode, boolean blocking) {
    int fd = posix.open(path.toString(),
        OpenFlags.O_WRONLY.intValue() | OpenFlags.O_CREAT.intValue(),
        mode);
    if (fd < 0) {
        throwErrno("open", path);
    }
    int operation = LOCK_EX;
    if (!blocking) {
        operation |= LOCK_NB;
    }
    int ret = posix.flock(fd, operation);
    if (ret != 0) {
        throwErrno("flock", path);
    }
    return fd;
}
```

This is just minimal demo code. I would recommend to return an `AutoClosable` that releases the log when closed.